# Pandas dataframe to azure mysql

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mysql-connector

I am trying to save a pandas dataframe to a mysql MS Azure database. I have a cert file and a successful connection ( I think). But for some reason the pandas `to_sql` method won't work because of the following error:

> pandas.errors.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM
> sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments
> converted during string formatting

Is there something I need to be aware of when saving dataframes to an azure mysql database?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

df = pd.read_csv('files/exports//table.csv')
print(df.head())
conn = pymysql.connect(host='DNS name of my database',
                       user='user',
                       passwd="password",
                       db='databasename',
                       ssl_ca="somecert.crt.pem",
                       ssl_disabled=False)

df.to_sql(con=conn, name='tablename')
```

Glad for any help I can receive.

Best regards,

André

Comment: Many of the pandas built in sql methods are to be used specifically with sqlalchemy (or, for some reason, sqlite db connections...). You can see here it's trying to query a sqlite metadata table in your mysql database which isn't going to work for obvious reasons. Switch your `pymysql` to sqlalchemy and give it another go.

Comment: Hi, ok that worked. I thought the sqlalchemy way was deprecated but it seems I was wrong with this assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by JNevill the solution was to change the connection to sqlalchemy. Here is the code which was working:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user:password@server-dns-name/database',connect_args={
            "ssl_ca": "paththothecertfile.pem"} )


df = pd.read_csv('table.csv')
df.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='table',if_exists='replace')
```